# Why does -XImplicitParams work only from the command line, not a pragma?

Tags: haskell, ghc, pragma, compiler-options, language-extension

Why does `-XImplicitParams` work from the command line but not the OPTIONS_GHC pragma?

I've found that `ghc t.hs` throws a `parse error on input 'a'` if `t.hs` contains the following code, while `ghc -XImplicitParams t.hs` works fine.  Ditto `ghci`.

```
{- OPTIONS_GHC -XImplicitParams -}
f :: (?a :: Int) => Int -> Int
f b = ?a + b
g c = f $ c+1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would need to be a pragma, with `{-# ... #-}` delimiters. Better than an `OPTIONS_GHC` pragma is a

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
```

pragma.